# Redirecting a form with multiple submit inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which has **3** separate input with a type of "submit".

The first two inputs output a message once they are clicked, but the final one is supposed to redirect to another page however it is not doing this. *I think this is because the form is submitting and refreshing the page before it gets to the JavaScript for redirection.*

Here is my code:

**FORM.php**

```
<form class="form" id="form" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <br>
         <input type="email" name="email" id="email" maxlength="80" value="<?php echo $email ?>" placeholder="Enter Your Email" /><br /><br>
        <input id="button4" type="submit" value="Get Security Question" name="submit2" style="cursor:pointer;"/><br> 
            <br><input type="password" name="securitya"id="securitya" maxlength="20" value="<?php echo $securitya ?>" placeholder="Enter Your Security Answer" /> <br />
        <br>
    <input id="button3"type="submit" value="Check Answer" name="submit" style="cursor:pointer;"/>
    <br>
        <br><input type="password" name="newpassword" id="newpassword" maxlength="20" placeholder="Enter Your New Password" /> <br />

    <br><input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" maxlength="20" placeholder="Re-Enter Your New Password" /> <br />

<br>
    <input id="button2" type="submit" value="Change Password" disabled="disabled" name="submit" style="cursor:pointer;"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(function(){
        $("#button2").click(function(){                                         
        $(".error").hide();
        var hasError = false;
        var passwordVal = $("#newpassword").val();
        var checkVal = $("#confirmpassword").val();
        if (passwordVal == '') {
            $("#newpassword").after('<span class="error" >Please enter a password.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        } else if (checkVal == '') {
            $("#confirmpassword").after('<span class="error">Please re-enter your password.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        } else if (passwordVal != checkVal ) {   
            $("#confirmpassword").after('<span id = "pass" class="error">Passwords do not match.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        }
        if(hasError == true) { return false; }
        else {

            $("#button2").after('<span class="error">Passwords accepted.</span>');

            window.location.href='adminsignin.php';
            }

    }); 
});
```

What is weird about this is the message 'Passwords accepted'  appears on screen for a split second, but there is no redirection to 'adminsignin.php'

Can anyone help?

Comment: It does not redirect, because button is disabled

Comment: I have a JavaScript function in place so when all fields have content the button is no longer disabled. #Skwl'd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your javascript, pass the event into the click handler, and preventDefault().

```
$("#butotn2").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   ...
}
```

the submit button has default behavior, so you'll want to prevent its default behavior so that you can perform your operations and then redirect with your window.location.href.

please try changing to `document.location = 'your URL';`

Comment: I have just tried this preventDefault method and it still doesnt redirect. and the data is being sent and retrieved from a mySQL database using php that I havent included in this post

Comment: @oggle0901 please try changing to `document.location = 'your URL';

Comment: @oggle0901 you're welcome. I'm guessing you're on IE? For some reason I always need to use document.locaiton in IE whereas window.location works everywhere else.

Comment: Surprisingly not, I'm using Chrome

Comment: Prefix, please check your code.  You have mismatched quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks, @Sparky , fixed. :)